# HTML table from python dictionary

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to modify part of code in a flask application. What the flask app does so far:

It has around 20 links, when someone clicks on the link it returns .json objects (formed by python dictionaries via jsonify).

What I am trying to do:

Return the same results in a table format that can be potentially extracted to .csv

I created the following function:

```
def tab_out(output = {}):
    return render_template('output_tab.html',output=output)
```

that sends the dictionary out to an html page, that contains this:

```
{% block content %}
    <body>
        <pre>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Header 1</th>
                    <th>Header 2</th>
                    <th>Header 3</th>
                    <th>Header 4</th> 
                    <th>Header 5</th>
                    <th>Header 6</th>
                </tr>
                {% for key_1, value in output.items() %}
                    {% for key in value.keys() %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {{ key_1 | safe }}
                            </td>
                            
                            <td>
                                {{ key | safe }}
                            </td>
                            
                            <td>
                                {{ value[key]["Header_3"] }}
                            </td>
                            
                            <td>
                                {{ value[key]["Header_4"] }}
                            </td>
                            
                            <td>
                                {{ value[key]["Header_5"] }}
                            </td>
                            
                            <td>
                                {{ value[key]["Header_6"] }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>                        
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </pre>
    </body>
{% endblock %}
```

What's the issue:

I need to make it dynamic.

Each page has different headers.
In each page the resulted .json comes from a dictionary that has sub-dictionaries and the number of keys in each dictionary can be different. So I can't specify the headers before hand. I want them dynamically created. Maybe flatten out the dictionary (up to a level 2 let's say) if there's 3 sub-dictionaries and get the results as headers and the rest as values.

I've read a couple similar questions in sa, but none of them really helped me. Any ideas?

Comment: can you share a sample json?

Comment: Is the dict that is used is a flat dict or a nested one?

Comment: @balderman It is a nested dict. hprakash, I can't. It's nested dictionaries, and the result different for every html page (route).

Comment: @Lev After you will flatten the duct - you will be able to use my answer. See below

Answer (score 0):

The jinja code below will generate HTML table from any FLAT dict.
The headers are dynamic. `entry_list` is a list of dicts. Your code should create a flat dict.

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <!-- table header -->
  {% if entry_list %}
  <tr>
     {% for key in entry_list [0] %}
     <th> {{ key }} </th>
     {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endif %}

  <!-- table rows -->
  {% for dict_item in entry_list %}
  <tr>
     {% for value in dict_item.values() %}
     <td> {{ value }} </td>
     {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```